# oracle v$session - inactive and waiting

Tags: oracle

I have read that the `STATUS INACTIVE` is harmless and not locking any further queries. but at the same time the `STATE says WAITING`. And my program is actually keeps waiting for a query to execute. I do not have privilage to Kill any queries.

So how can this queries get terminated? Or how to check the max time out for these queries?. Also can anyone tell me how  much time is this ? `8147476214`  is it milliseconds ? i get insane hours if devided by 60 3 times

```
WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO    SID SERIAL#  STATUS STATE
8147476214  -1  363 17919   INACTIVE    WAITING
8147060408  -1  600 30087   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463255  -1  1522    31615   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463255  -1  1433    19943   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463239  -1  204 3751    INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463217  -1  203 17423   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463217  -1  300 25717   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463204  -1  703 12277   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463193  -1  361 10209   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288463144  -1  457 35447   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082277  -1  102 49705   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082274  -1  216 14829   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082274  -1  58  62561   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082273  -1  308 11485   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082273  -1  497 45153   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082258  -1  1289    15497   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082243  -1  1526    48083   INACTIVE    WAITING
1288082224  -1  992 34411   INACTIVE    WAITING
300678  -1  451 11433   ACTIVE  WAITING
261893  -1  304 30921   ACTIVE  WAITING
241839  -1  50  32641   ACTIVE  WAITING
228894  -1  11  42861   ACTIVE  WAITING
79480   -1  996 19657   ACTIVE  WAITING
40677   -1  896 28523   ACTIVE  WAITING
25609   -1  845 55041   ACTIVE  WAITING
12517   -1  115 25819   ACTIVE  WAITING
2       54  47749   ACTIVE  WAITED SHORT TIME
2       1283    50745   ACTIVE  WAITED SHORT TIME
0   -1  548 51351   ACTIVE  WAITING
0   0   405 44925   ACTIVE  WAITING
```